# how to print the soap request (request is sending using php curl)?

Tags: php, soap

I am sending a soap request using PHP `curl()`. I need to print my request, so that I can have a look into my request and understand weather it is going in a right format.

But I don't know how to print my request out. I tried `getlastRequest()` but it is not working. Can anybody help me out??

Sara

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$soapServer = new SoapServer(null, array('uri' => "urn://l/res"));
// managed functions
// $soapServer->addFunction("...");
// $soapServer->addFunction("..."); 
// .....
$xml_data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

And if you want validate xml soap request

```
$parser = xml_parser_create("UTF-8");
if (!xml_parse($parser, $xml_data, true)) {
     $error = "Cannot parse XML: " .
              xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($parser)) .
              " at line: " . xml_get_current_line_number($parser) .
              ", column: " . xml_get_current_column_number($parser);
     // Send error via SOAP
     $soapServer->fault("500", $error);
}
```